# Show that if the span of a lin. indep vector A is a proper subset of the vector space, then there exists a proper superset A that is also lin. indep.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am new to proofs and I could use some guidance. I have to prove this claim:

Suppose $A \subseteq V$ (where $V$ is a real vector space) and that $A$ is linearly independent. Also, the $span(A) \subsetneq V $ (proper set).

Then there exists a set $A' \subseteq V$ such that $A \subsetneq A'$ and that $A'$ is linearly independent.

I am not sure what to do. I started with the definition of lin. independence for both $X$ and $X'$, but I don't know what to do with this $span(X) \subsetneq Z $ which I guess is the piece I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mbox{span}(A)$ is a proper subspace of $V$, there exists $v$ such that $v\not\in\mbox{span}(A)$. Plainly, $\{v\}\cup A$ is linearly independent.